Why I'm getting error when I use Material Badge in next.js
Why I'm getting an error when I use Material Badge in my next.js project?
enter image description here
This is my markup and code:
<div className="py-1" key={keys}>
    <Badge badgeContent={pathname == item?.link ? 0 : item?.badgeContent} color="primary">
        <div className={`link ${pathname == item?.link && 'active'}`}>
            <Link href={item?.link} className='d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center'>
            {item?.icon}
            </Link>
        </div>
    </Badge>
</div>

